# LibreOffice won't run on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, libreoffice

I need to install LibreOffice for headless use through the PyUno bridge so I can use unoconv on a CentOS and Ubuntu server. I installed it on the Ubuntu machine by getting the deb package, extracting it, and using 'sudo dpkg -i *.deb' to install it and it's working as expected.

On the CentOS machine however after extracting I installed using 'yum localinstall *.rpm'. After it was done I tried starting it but I got an error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I used 'yum resolvedep "libGL.so.1"' which came out to "mesa-libGL-11.0.7-4.el6.i686", and I installed it and according to the system libGL.so.1 is installed, but LibreOffice gives the same error. The machine is CentOS 6.7 and LibreOffice is 5.0.6.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using the version of LibreOffice that is bundled with CentOS? Do you have a specific requirement to use LibreOffice 5.x?

Comment: Not really but as far as I can tell when I gained access to the system it didn't have LibreOffice on it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have access to this machine's graphical desktop you can run the following command to find out which LibreOffice packages are available:

```
yum list 'libreoffice*'
```

Then choose from the list the ones you want and install them with:

```
yum install <package> ...
```

Comment: Would I have to uninstall my previous install first?

Comment: I think you should, yes.

Comment: Ok I got it to work after I uninstalled the tar.gz install, installed from the repository (I think), which still didn't work. It did install some 60 packages, and the uninstall command only uninstalled around 14 which I guess leftover some dependencies. After that I installed my original tar.gz again and now it's working. It'd be nice if the rpm packages could resolve dependencies on its own.